# Installing Heroku gem to my root directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, heroku, root

How do I install the Heroku gem to my root directory? I tried sudo gem install heroku, but this doesn't seem to work. Any other suggestions? I am working with OSX.

Comment: Any output of the gem install command might be rather helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend installing gems in locations other than where RVM or gem wants to install the files, but you can override the install location like this:

```
sudo gem install heroku --install-dir /path/to/install/into
```

Where /path/to/install/into is where you want to install the gem.